# Plotting the co-ordinates of the compositional mean on a ternary plot with ggtern

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtern

I have a compositional set of data investigating sedentary behaviour, sleep and physical activity. Each of these data points is a proportion of time. I want to plot this on a ternary plot using `ggtern` and have done as follows which results in the below output.

```
library(ggtern)
library(gtools)
library(zCompositions)

comp_df <- as.data.frame(data[,c("id","PA", "SB", "Sleep")])

ggtern(data = comp_df, aes(Sleep, SB, PA)) +
  geom_mask() +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme_showarrows() +
  geom_confidence_tern(colour = "black", breaks = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75))
```

[image]

Now this is most of the way there. However I want to add a data point that plots the compositional mean of this dataset on the ternary plot, and also labels the co-ordinates of this mean in a specific way. I've use the `epicoda` package from [GitHub](https://github.com/OxWearables/epicoda) to identify the compositional mean and add the appropriate labels as below.

```
comp_labels <- c("Sleep", "SB", "PA")
library(epicoda)
cm <- comp_mean(comp_df, comp_labels = comp_labels, units = "hr/day")
```

Then, I can add this easily to my ternary plot with the addition of another `geom_point()` argument which results in the same output but with the additional point for the compositional mean.

```
ggtern(data = comp_df, aes(Sleep, SB, PA)) +
  geom_mask() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data = cm) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme_showarrows() +
  geom_confidence_tern(colour = "black", breaks = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75))
```

What I want to be able to do is add lines to label the mean with both percentages and time like this image. Any assistance here would be very much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This is a well-asked question (q). Unfortunately, one important part is still missing. Please make your q reproducible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example Share (parts of) `comp_df` as text using `dput()` or provide toy data.

Comment: Additionally, specify from which library function `comp_mean` comes from.

Comment: @thothal, it is stated above the respective code block: https://github.com/OxWearables/epicoda

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you did not provide any data, so this code comes untested, but `geom_[TLR]line` should help you. For example to mark the mixture `20%/20%/60%` you could use:

```r
ggtern(data = comp_df, aes(Sleep, SB, PA)) +
  geom_mask() +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme_showarrows() +
  geom_confidence_tern(colour = "black", breaks = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)) +
  geom_Tline(Tintercept = .2) +
  geom_Lline(Lintercept = .2) +
  geom_Rline(Rintercept = .6)
```

That is, something like:

```r
geom_Tline(Tintercept = cm$SB) +
  geom_Lline(Lintercept = cm$Sleep) +
  geom_Rline(Rintercept = cm$PA)
```

should do the trick.